# Checkmarx says document.url is unsafe

Tags: javascript, xss, checkmarx

We have a potential XSS warning on this code:

```
if (someCondition) {
    //location.reload();
    window.location = document.URL;
}
```

The message is:

> The application's FunctionName embeds untrusted data in the generated output with location, at line 433 of Directory\CodeFile.js. This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.

Is there any actual vulnerability here (and if yes, what should we use instead, knowing that `location.reload()` wasn't satisfying?), or should I simply flag this as Not Exploitable and move on?

Answer (score 0):

URL escape the document.URL before passing the value to window.location

```
if (someCondition) {
    location.href = encodeURIComponent(document.URL);
}
```

Comment: I finally managed to try it, and it didn't work. The address ``http://localhost/MyWebSite/Home/Home.aspx somehow ended up as `http://localhost/MyWebSite/Home/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FMyWebSite%2FHome%2FHome.aspx`, which crashes.

Comment: can you please try the updated code?

Comment: The updated code has the same effect.